# Fast formula to find the coordinate of the 4th vertex of the square by three others

Tags: algorithm

There are 4 possible figures on the coordinate system.

```
XO
XX

OX
XX

XX
OX

XX
XO
```

It is kind of square, each X or O have dimensions of 1x1.

What's the fastest way to find the coordinates (Xo, Yo) if you have coordinates (X1, Y1), (X2, Y2), (X3, Y3) of XXX in that figure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `(x1 ^ x2 ^ x3, y1 ^ y2 ^ y3)`. For each of x and y, you've got two coordinates the same, and a different one. Xor'ing them together causes the pair of coordinates that are the same to cancel. This works whatever units you're using for the square.

For example: given `(10, 20), (50, 30), (10, 30)` you get `(10^50^10, 20^30^30)` which is `(50, 20)`.

Comment: Very elegant way, I'd have gone with an ugly if-else construct.

Comment: This solution is only possible if the coordinates are axes parallel. For example, if the coordinates are `(10,16) ; (15,11); (10,6)`. Then the fourth coordinate will be `(5,11)`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's call the missing corner `P4`, the diagonal opposite corner `P1`, the other two `P2` and `P3`.  The you calculate the missing corner as

```
P4=P2+P3-P1
```

The remaining problem is to identify the opposite corner `P1`. So given three points `A`, `B` and `C` you calculate `|A-B|`, `|B-C|`, `|A-C|`, or the squares of that.  The two points with the largest distance can be identified with `P2` and `P3`, the remaining one is `P1`

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes are called n0, n1, n2, n3 in clockwise-rotation, then

```
n3 = n0 + (n2 - n1)
```

Doesn't really get faster than two subtractions and two additions (one for each coordinate). If you need any other vertex than n3, you can simply modify the system.